# Snowflake - grant usage on set of views only

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have multiple views in my database. And wanted to grant select access to views which starts with a pattern. How can I do that?

I tried the below. But did not work.

GRANT SELECT ON ALL VIEWS LIKE 'my_view_%' TO <role/user>;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way you can generate all the Grants statements by using the following statements and executing the grants later on.

```
select 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || TABLE_NAME  || ' TO ROLE  role_name;' from information_schema.views where TABLE_NAME like '%A%' ;
```